# Pandas Panel as numpy multidimensional array

Tags: python, pandas, panel

I'm new with pandas. I try to do an example within I have a grid of points in three-dimension, the dimension of grid is **N1 x N2 x N3**.
Each point in the grid contain some data (`numpy.ndarray`, `float` number, etc). By example: at `Point(0,0,0): 'date' = 18`, `'temperature array' = numpy.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])`.

Now my aim is to create a pandas "table" (I guest a `pandas.Panel`) so that when I call `table['date'][Point(0,0,0)]`, the results should return : `18` and when I call `table['temperature array'][Point(0,0,0)]`, it returns `numpy.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])`.

Could you post a simple example, it will help me a lots.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Panel4D is probably what you're looking for. It essentially creates a multilevel index from your first 3 dimensions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# 100 x 100 x 100 x 3 array
data = np.random.randn(100,100,100,3)
data[0,0,0]
# out[]:
#     array([ 0.85284721, -0.04883839, -0.09375558])

table = pd.Panel4D(data)
table.ix[0,0,0]
# out[]:
#     minor
#     0    0.852847
#     1   -0.048838
#     2   -0.093756
#     Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out how to store a numpy array in a single cell of a Pandas NDFrame, and I doubt it would be a good idea even if I succeeded. 
Pandas NDFrames use NumPy arrays to store the underlying data. To store a NumPy array as a value inside a NumPy array, the outer NumPy array would need to be of object dtype, which prevents NumPy (and Pandas) from applying fast numeric routines to the array. So nesting a NumPy array inside an NDFrame (such as a Panel or DataFrame) would hurt performance.

You could instead use a DataFrame with a MultiIndex:

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0,0,0),(0,0,1)])
table = pd.DataFrame([(18,1,2,3,4,5,6),
                      (19,10,20,30,40,50,60)], index=index,
                     columns=['date','t0','t1','t2','t3','t4','t5'])
print(table)
#        date  t0  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
# 0 0 0    18   1   2   3   4   5   6
#     1    19  10  20  30  40  50  60

print(table.ix[(0,0,0),'date'])
# 18

print(table.ix[(0,0,1),'t0':'t5'].reshape(2,-1))
# [[10 20 30]
#  [40 50 60]]
```

Comment: "Flat is better than nested" applies to code only. And there it means "as flat as possible".

Comment: @HeinzKurt: Yes, you are right. Thanks for the correction.